# Divide value from cat

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cat

The goal of my script is to get the /cache partitions location (Which works) and then get the block size of that location and divide it by 1024. Then I want to output the size, I've tried many possible ways but I cannot get it to work right.

```
#!/bin/bash -v

if [ -e mounts ]; then
rm -f mounts
fi;

./adb -d shell "mount" > mounts

export CACHEPARTITION=`cat mounts | grep /cache`; 
var=$(echo $CACHEPARTITION | awk -F"/" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}')   
set -- $var

echo "Cache mount point: "$1/$2/$3;

export CACHEPART=$1/$2/$3
```

This exports for example: /dev/block/mmcblk0p16 to the file "mounts"

```
if [ -e cachepartition ]; then
rm -f cachepartition
fi;

./adb -d shell "blockdev --getsize64 '${CACHEPART}'" > cachepartition
```

This exports for example: 104857600 which needs to be divided by 1024 down below

```
export CACHESIZE=`cat cachepartition`; 
DIVIDE=1024

export OUTPUT=`expr ${CACHESIZE} / ${DIVIDE}`

echo ${OUTPUT}
```

Instead of catting the value can I pipe it? and make it actually do the division.
I'm kinda noob at bash scripting, this was the easiest possible method I thought of, but it's still to hard for me it seems lol

Some help on this is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can take output of command using ` or $():

```
part_size_bytes=$(./adb -d shell "blockdev --getsize64 '${CACHEPART}'")
# divide it by 1024
part_size_kb=$(($part_size_bytes / 1024))
echo "cache size is $part_size_kb kb."
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this is a step in the good direction. But the thing is that adb is a binary that needs to be executed and redirects its output to the value.

If I change it to: 

part_size_bytes=$(./adb -d shell "blockdev --getsize64 '${CACHEPART}'")

it outputs     / 1024")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
cache size is  kb.

Comment: `./` is needed because this file is in the current directory not in the search paths..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
CACHESIZE=$(./adb -d shell "blockdev --getsize64 '${CACHEPART}'")
DIVIDE=1024
```

For simple integer division:

```
OUTPUT=$((CACHESIZE/DIVIDE))
```

For floating point division:

```
OUTPUT=$(bc -l <<< "$CACHESIZE"/"$DIVIDE")
```

You also have a [Useless Use of Cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). Instead of:

```
cat mounts | grep /cache
```

write:

```
grep /cache mounts
```

There is a [Useless Use of Echo](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2012/12/useless-use-of-echo.html) too. Instead of:

```
echo $CACHEPARTITION | awk -F"/" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

write

```
awk -F"/" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' <<< "$CACHEPARTITION"
```

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer, and the fixes of the useless commands, however, I still get this error: ")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M

Comment: You might have `^M` (Windows line endings) in your script. Are you editing the script on Windows? If so you need to fix your script by running the `dos2unix` command on it.

Comment: I'm working in linux so that's kinda strange, I tried to ran the dos2unix command but the error still shows, btw, does this: CACHESIZE=$(./adb -d shell "blockdev --getsize64 '${CACHEPART}'") actually pipe it to CACHEPART? 

if I do: echo $CACHESIZE

but OUTPUT=$((CACHESIZE/DIVIDE)) still results into: ")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

Comment: what does `echo "_${CACHESIZE}_"` output?

Comment: there is no piping. The command `CACHESIZE=$(./adb -d shell "blockdev --getsize64 '${CACHEPART}'")`, runs the `adb ...` command and stores its output into the `CACHESIZE` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the _${CACHESIZE}_ var output the right value (its _104857600) without the "_" its good. but when it's trying to be divided it gives this error:

OUTPUT=$((CACHESIZE/DIVIDE))
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

SO i was searching for this quote, but I cannot remove any of them or it will break.

Comment: Do you have quotes in CACHESIZE? please answer my previous question: what does `echo "_${CACHESIZE}_"` output?

Comment: Sorry, yes it has: CACHESIZE=$(./adb -d shell "blockdev --getsize64 '${CACHEPART}'")

When I change it to this: CACHESIZE=$(./adb -d shell 'blockdev --getsize64 '${CACHEPART}'') it results the same error, but when I totally remove them like this: CACHESIZE=$(./adb -d shell blockdev --getsize64 '${CACHEPART}') it results in a parameter error from the binary blockdev. The "_${CACHESIZE}_" returns: _104857600
in echo.  With and without quotes it results in the same thing, the problem is that its just not working in the (( )) expr

Comment: Did `echo "_${CACHESIZE}_"` print out `_104857600` or `_104857600_`?

Comment: echo "_${CACHESIZE}_" printed: _104857600  (so without the ending underscore)

Comment: The underscore is not showing correctly in my reply, but the var has both underscores (which aren't visible for some reason) with the quotes and the output only has the first

Comment: oh, you're not getting the last underscore? That means that your adb command is not just returning a number but is also returning a newline or some whitespace. That's why the division fails.

Comment: Almost got it!

CACHESIZE=$(./adb -d shell "blockdev --getsize64 '${CACHEPART}'")
DIVIDE=1024        results in: Cache mount point: dev/block/mmcblk0p16
/10247600
which is the right number!, only need to strip the slash :)

Fixed it! Thanks a bunch!!! Sorry I cannot give you +1 yet, only have 6 rep

Comment: O btw the format is still wrong I notice, when I use echo ${CACHESIZE} / 1024 it results in: " / 102400" and its the right number but the format that comes before it is of course not wanted :P